# SQL Calculations based by field type and group by the type

Tags: sql, calculated-field

Database includes FamID, TicketType and Amt
I want to get a calculation for total amount for each tickettype for each family and sort by family high to low based on total for all tickettypes.

Database values are:

```
FamID           TicketType             Amt
1                1                     10
1                1                     10
1                2                     20
1                3                     30
2                2                     20
2                1                     10
2                1                     10
2                1                     10
2                3                     30
3                3                     30
3                3                     30
3                3                     30
```

Would like results to be

```
Family         Type 1         Type 2        Type 3         Total
3                0               0             90            90
2                30              20            30            80
1                20              20            30            70
```

Am I trying to do too much?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Does it support `PIVOT`? Do you know all posiible values of `TicketType` upfront?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never specified your RDBMS, but the following pivot query should work across most major ones with little modification:

```
SELECT t.`Type 1`, t.`Type 2`, t.`Type 3`,
    (t.`Type 1` + t.`Type 2` + 2*t.`Type 3`) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT FamID AS Family,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType = 1 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type 1`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType = 2 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type 2`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType = 3 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type 3`,
    FROM Tickets
    GROUP BY FamID
) t
ORDER BY t.Total DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfect.  I am using MS SQL. Appreciate the quick feedback.

Comment: Sorry Tim - never used this before so wasn't sure on the process. I have an extension of this question - should I ask here or start a new question?

Comment: You can let me know what the extension is.  If it be small, I will answer here.  If large, then yes you should ask a new question and reference this one, and feel free to take my query to use.

Comment: In this case the total should be Type1+Type2+(Type3*2) - I can get Type3 to double by adding *2 after that Amt - but how do I do it in the total?  It makes a difference in the order by to show high to low totals.

Comment: @KathyKaiserLees I have updated the query to meet your new specifications.  I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day

Comment: Tim - the new query doesn't work. This is what I have.
Select t.'Type1', t.'Type2', t.'Type3', t.'Type5', t.'Type4',(t.'Type1' + t.'Type2' + t.'Type3' + t.'Type4' + t.'Type5') as Total FROM ( SELECT FamID as Family,
SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType =1 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type1`,
SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType =2 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type2`,
SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType = 3 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type3`,
SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType =4 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type4`,
SUM(CASE WHEN TicketType = 5 THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) AS `Type5'
FROM Passes1
GROUP BY FamID)  t 
ORDER BY t.'Total' DESC

Comment: No error - just no results...Let me see how to turn on error reporting - never used it before...

Comment: I get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Type1', t.'Type2', t.'Type3', t.'Type5', t.'Type4',(t.'Type1' + t.'Type2' + t.'' at line 1

Comment: You need to use backticks when referring to the column names in the outer query like this: `SELECT t.\`Type 1\` ...`  You are using single quotes like this: `SELECT t.'Type 1' ...`  The query is fine and of course you must adjust it to your own environment.

Comment: That did it.. Thank you.